# Enabling gzip compression for Jboss

Tags: http, configuration, jboss, compression, application-server

How is gzip compression for Jboss 5.1.0 enabled?

Within the tomcat http connector right? I cant remember where this file is stored, server.xml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file is under server.xml and you are correct in stating that you have to updated the http connector.

Following link is info for tomcat, but same applies to JBoss except location of server.xml file. I believe you need to update the server.xml under deploy\jbossweb.sar\

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat.html

Answer (score 16):

edit jboss\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml

Edit this:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

to be more like this:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" compression="on" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript, application/x-javascript,application/javascript" 
connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

You can refer to connector config info for further details please see:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 15):

To add gzip compression in **JBoss 7.1.1**, you can edit standalone/configuration/standalone.xml and add:

```
       ...
    </extensions>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
        <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="text/javascript,text/css,text/html"/>
    </system-properties>
```

Restart the server and check with developer tools or in the HTTP header if it is enabled.

Comment: Hello @doonot I have implemented this code on my jBoss EAP 6.1 and It was working fine when I was working on my local server. But when I moved to actual server environment the changes are not getting reflected. 

My server is jBoss Server EAP 6.1 and is working on Linux OS.

http://stackoverflow.com/users/569077/doonot

Comment: @doonot, I tried similar approach but not worked looks something I am missing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011480/pagespeed-enable-compression-in-jboss please help

Answer (score 2):

In Jboss EAP 7.0 this worked for me:

edit: Standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">   <!-- SEARCH FOR THIS: urn:jboss:domain:undertow -->
  <buffer-cache name="default"/>  
  <server name="default-server">  
  <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>  
  <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">  
  (...)

  <!-- ADD THIS FOR GZIP COMPRESSION -->
  <filter-ref name="gzipFilter" predicate="exists['%{o,Content-Type}'] and regex[pattern='(?:application/javascript|text/css|text/html|text/xml|application/json)(;.*)?', value=%{o,Content-Type}, full-match=true]"/>  
  <!-- /GZIP COMPRESSION -->

  </host>  
  </server>  
(...)  
  <filters>  
  (...)  

  <!-- ADD THIS FOR GZIP COMPRESSION -->
  <gzip name="gzipFilter"/>  
  <!-- /GZIP COMPRESSION -->

  </filters>  
</subsystem>
```

Restart the server

Comment: This doesn't work on a domain setup on EAP 7.0.